# create a subset in an array following the value that I have

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to rebuild an array based on the type of data and the data I have.

So I want to create a subset inside the modules array that depends on the number of modules in my database, and the number of subset names will also vary according to the module.

I want to repeat the number of subsets according to the module I have in the database.

Example:

```php
[modules] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => "id of module"
        [name] => Array (
            [en] => "name of module"
        ),
        (
            [es] => "name of module"
        ),
        [number_courses] => "number"
        [sub_names] => Array (
            [0] => name of sub module
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: `"I want to ...."` but you appear to not have tried anything so this seems like a `"can someone write my code"` type of request

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here

Answer (score 0):

To create a subset in the array based on the number of modules and sub-names, try the following.

```
$modules = [
    [
        'id' => 'module1',
        'name' => ['en' => 'Module 1', 'es' => 'Módulo 1'],
        'number_courses' => 3,
        'sub_names' => ['Submodule 1', 'Submodule 2', 'Submodule 3']
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'module2',
        'name' => ['en' => 'Module 2', 'es' => 'Módulo 2'],
        'number_courses' => 2,
        'sub_names' => ['Submodule A', 'Submodule B']
    ]
];

$rebuiltArray = [];
foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $subsets = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $module['number_courses']; $i++) {
        $subsets[] = [
            'name' => $module['sub_names'][$i]
        ];
    }
    $module['subsets'] = $subsets;
    $rebuiltArray[] = $module;
}

print_r($rebuiltArray);
```